# VSHost crash, REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE loading Specific Project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, comexception, vshost32

Whenever I load a solution in Visual Studio with a specific project set as the startup project, I get a VSHost32.exe crash. If I keep on going and launch the application, I get a COMException:

```
{"Invalid value for registry (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040153 (REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE))"}
```

With a stacktrace:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetDeveloperPath()
at System.AppDomain.SetupFusionStore(AppDomainSetup info)
at System.AppDomain.SetupDomain(Boolean allowRedirects, String path, String configFile)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can occur when a project's config file has developmentMode set, but the machine doesn't have a devPath set.

```
<runtime>
    <developmentMode developerInstallation="true"/>
</runtime>
```

Removing that will fix it up.

Comment: You can also set DEVPATH in your environment, if you don't want to, or can't, change the exe's config file.

Comment: This may also be in the machine.config file, for example  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config. I've occasionally set it there and then forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config and remove the below setting from your machine config

<developmentModedeveloperinstallation=”true”/>