# WPF RichTextBox SpellCheck ComException

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, richtextbox, spell-checking

I've got an exception while trying to enable spell checking on some Windows 8.1 machines (both have latest updates, OS language is russian and .NET framework 4.7 is russian) saying:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid value for
>   registry (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040153 (REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE))
>   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
>   at Windows.Data.Text.WordsSegmenter..ctor(String language) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.ReflectionHelper.ReflectionNew[TArg1](Type
>   type, TArg1 arg1) at
>   MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.Data.Text.WordsSegmenter..ctor(String
>   language) at
>   MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.Data.Text.WordsSegmenter.Create(String
>   language, Boolean shouldPreferNeutralSegmenter) at
>   System.Windows.Documents.WinRTSpellerInterop.EnsureWordBreakerAndSpellCheckerForCulture(CultureInfo
>   culture, Boolean throwOnError) at
>   System.Windows.Documents.WinRTSpellerInterop..ctor() at
>   System.Windows.Documents.SpellerInteropBase.CreateInstance() at
>   System.Windows.Documents.Speller.EnsureInitialized() at
>   System.Windows.Documents.Speller.SetCustomDictionaries(CustomDictionarySources
>   dictionaryLocations, Boolean add) at
>   System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor.SetCustomDictionaries(Boolean add)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.SpellCheck.OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object
>   value)

This code can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
var richTextBox = new RichTextBox();
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(richTextBox,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
richTextBox.SetValue(SpellCheck.IsEnabledProperty, true);
```

While investigation this issue I found that exception is thrown from `s_WinRTType.ReflectionNew<string>(language);` where **s_WinRTType describes type "Windows.Data.Text.WordsSegmenter, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime**. WordsSegmenter seems to be WinRT component so I can't see what's going on inside it. I want to know why does it throw REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE / which value it looks for and how should it look like?
Thank you!

Update 1.
I also saw this component's key exists in registry:
[image]
So probably this component throws exception by itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **language features** which is different from a **language pack** via control panel or using DISM. For me this required .Net 4.7 and is working for windows 10 build 1709 (fall creators update). I don't know if this is possible on Windows 8.

If you have proper access to windows update (not behind WSUS) you could try to install it

Dism /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Language.Basic~~~en-US~0.0.1.0

To check the installed features this shows all installed options:

dism /online /get-capabilities /limitaccess

Background info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-capabilities-package-servicing-command-line-options

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/08/31/adding-features-including-net-3-5-to-windows-10/

This last link explaines there is another version 2 of features on demand.
For me it solved an issue.

Using the feature-on-demand isos (downloaded them from your msdn subscription):

for windows 10 (don't know if this is available on windows 8):
en_windows_10_features_on_demand_part_1_version_1709_updated_sept_2017_x64_dvd_100090755
en_windows_10_features_on_demand_part_2_version_1709_updated_sept_2017_x64_dvd_100090754

extract them and install:

dism /online /add-package /packagepath:d:\features\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-en-us-Package.cab

PS: did you Google for REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE: [VSHost crash, REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE loading Specific Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026168/vshost-crash-regdb-e-invalidvalue-loading-specific-project)

EXAMPLE:

You can create a wpf test application with the following code:
This reads the AvailableInputLanguages that can be used. (for me it doesn't show the 4 languages from .Net 4 only the ones I install with Dism.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}"
          SelectionChanged="OnLanguageSelectionChanged"
          DisplayMemberPath="NativeName"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Row="1"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         AcceptsTab="True"
         SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
         Text="Hello world"/>
</Grid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AvailableLanguages = new ObservableCollection<CultureInfo>();

        foreach (CultureInfo culterInfo in InputLanguageManager.Current.AvailableInputLanguages)
        {
            AvailableLanguages.Add(culterInfo);
        }

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CultureInfo> AvailableLanguages
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<CultureInfo>)GetValue(AvailableLanguagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AvailableLanguagesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AvailableLanguagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AvailableLanguages", typeof(ObservableCollection<CultureInfo>), typeof(MainWindow));


    private void OnLanguageSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo xmlLanguage = e.AddedItems[0] as CultureInfo;
        textBox.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(xmlLanguage.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: From here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx I read "In .NET Framework 4, WPF provides dictionaries for English, French, German, and Spanish." Is it false then?

Comment: I had to install them.

Comment: i will continue investigation, give you more details and probably mark your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this: start cmd (run as administrator)

```
Dism /online /Add-Capability /capabilityname:Language.Basic~~~en-US~0.0.1.0
```

Comment: Sadly, now I don't have 8.1 machine. The documentations says: "Spelling checker is supported only when WPF provides a default dictionary. In .NET Framework 4, WPF provides dictionaries for English, French, German, and Spanish." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1  . I wanted to avoid installing anything on customer's machine. Instead, I'd like to use that default dictionaries provided by WPF itself.